# Enum Inside Class

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to define an enum within a class but Eclipse continues to underline my code in the lovely red color. Here is what my code looks like for the most part:

```
package campusvilleFoodBank;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FoodArrayList {

    public enum Days {SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THUR, FRI, SAT}

    private Food [] foodArray;
    private int iterator;
    private boolean startIndexing;
    private static final int MAX = 24;

    public FoodArrayList(){
        foodArray = new Food [MAX];
        iterator = 0;
    }

    public FoodArrayList(int arraySize){
        foodArray = new Food [arraySize];
        iterator = 0;
    }
//Rest of code, with more complicated methods here
}
```

I must be missing something very simple, it's likely to be a syntax error.... The code that follows involves methods such as my `toString()`, some sorting methods for the `foodArray` instance variable, and things along those lines. I do not have a main method defined. I know that I can define an enum within a class definition and all of the code I've seen elsewhere is written nearly exactly the same as to what I have. However, Eclipse does not seem to recognize even the `enum` declaration and I don't believe I need to import anything.

Here is what I see in Eclipse for the code I have an error with:

[image: Code with error]

For comparison, here is some enum code from another, separate .java file that appears to be without error:

[image: Code without error]

Any assistance on this would be appreciated. Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: new Food? Where is the constructor for Food? Or class?

Comment: Don't you have more of an error message than "underlines in red"? Are you just missing a semicolon after the enum declaration?

Comment: Food is another class outside of FoodArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a couple of things but not related to `enum`, this is fine.

1. Seems to me that unless `Food` does exist, it **MUST** be created
2. If it **does** exist, then it must reside in a different package, which in turn you have to `import` it like this

   `import package_name.package2.Food;`
3. It could be that your `class` name is not **identical** to you `file` name

   `FoodArrayList`
4. Sometimes your `IDE` in this case `Eclipse` needs some help, try saving the file, closing it and opening it back up.

Comment: Food is another class outside of FoodArrayList

Comment: ¿Is it inside of the same package: `campusvilleFoodBank` ? if not the **import**

Comment: When you hover over the underlined errors. ¿What error message do you get?

Comment: They are both within the same package

Comment: When you hover over the underlined errors. ¿What error message do you get?

Comment: Seems like you could have an old version of JRE, take a look at this:

Answer (score -1):

you have a semicolon missing at the end of the enum in the FoodArrayList class

Comment: He doesn't semi-colons are only required in enum definitions if they also contain implementation